# Classes and If statements

Tags: python, class

```
def get_value(self):
        """Get the value on the face card:
           (Jack=11, Queen=12, King = 13), Ace = 1, others are face value 2-10"""

        #List that contains all the face cards that have a special value
        specialJ = ['J']
        specialK = ['K']
        specialQ = ['Q']

        #If the card is a jack, king, or queen, set the return value to 11,13,12
        if self.rank in specialJ:
            int_rank = '11'
        elif self.rank in specialK:
            int_rank = '13'
        elif self.rank in specialQ:
            int_rank = '12'
        #If the card is an ace, set the return value to 1
        elif self.rank == 'A':
            #Set the return value of the card to 1
            int_rank = '1'
        #If the card is not a face card, keep the same return value.
        else:
            int_rank = self.rank
```

I am trying to assign the jack a value of 11, the queen a value of 12, the king a value of 13 by getting it to check if the card is found in the special lists. This does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What *does* happen? Do you get an error message? Can you show us visible behavior that differs from what it should be?

Comment: Your comment `#If the card is a jack, king, or queen, set the return value to 12` does not match what your code actually does. Also, why are you using lists and `in`? Why not just `if self.rank == 'J'`?

Comment: Did you remember to `return` something? If this is your entire function, your function doesn't really do anything. It assigns a local `int_rank` variable that isn't visible outside a single function call and vanishes when the function returns.

Comment: As an aside, the couple of times I've made card games, I've used `self.rank` as an integer (1=A, 2-10, 11=J, 12=Q, 13=K) and defined __str__ to return a human-readable rank. That way I can do `for card in hand: print(card)` without any more mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list, like this

```
def get_value(self):
    my_cards = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
    return my_cards.index(self.rank) + 1
```

Even better, if you are going to access it often, dictionaries will give faster lookup

```
def get_value():
    my_cards = {'A': 1, '10': 10, 'K': 13, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, '3': 3, '2': 2, '5': 5, '4': 4, '7': 7, '6': 6, '9': 9, '8': 8}
    return my_cards.get(self.rank, -1)
```

Comment: @codehorse As per the question, it is `11`, `12` and `13` only :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_value():
    my_cards = {'A': 1, '10': 10, 'K': 13, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, '3': 3, '2': 2, '5': 5, '4': 4, '7': 7, '6': 6, '9': 9, '8': 8}
    return my_cards.get(self.rank, -1)
```

best way to do this